# Docker/Python/Django astimezone seems to be using DST from past year

Tags: django, python-3.x, docker, timezone, timezone-offset

I'm converting UTC datetimes to America/Santiago tz using dt.astimezone(my_tz) through a Django manage.py command, but it seems to be using DST from past year.

This code shows that DST changes at 12/08/2019, from -4 to -3, but this year this should be happening at 08/09/2019 (https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/chile/santiago)

```
import pytz
import datetime
tz = pytz.timezone("America/Santiago")
dt4offset = datetime.datetime.strptime(''.join('2019-08- 
10T10:00:00+00:00'.rsplit(':', 1)), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
dt3offset = datetime.datetime.strptime(''.join('2019-08- 
12T10:00:00+00:00'.rsplit(':', 1)), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')

now = datetime.datetime.now()
print('Now %s' % now)
print('UTC: %s -> America/Santiago: %s' % (dt4offset, 
dt4offset.astimezone(tz)))
print('UTC: %s -> America/Santiago: %s' % (dt3offset, 
dt3offset.astimezone(tz)))
```

It prints:

```
Now 2019-08-08 05:46:27.102422
UTC: 2019-08-10 10:00:00+00:00 -> America/Santiago: 2019-08-10 
06:00:00-04:00
UTC: 2019-08-12 10:00:00+00:00 -> America/Santiago: 2019-08-12 
07:00:00-03:00
```

Both of the tz convertions should have an offset of -4, but the second one changes acoording to the DST from 2018.

I've coded this in Repl.it and it works as its supposed to:

https://repl.it/@alejandrocarrasco/LightcyanHideousFlatassembler

I'm running this script from docker-compose exec command. I thought my docker container was outdated but it is ok:

```
docker-compose exec container date
```

Prints 'Thu Aug  8 05:52:25 UTC 2019' (and now() from the code above is also ok). So, I think there is a problem with my server/django config.

Both Ubuntu and Docker container have correct dates.

Also, in my ReactJs frontend, using moment and moment-timezone, this timezone convertion works nicely, both dates keep an offset of -4, the problem is only happening in my backend, I think inside the docker container.

My version of python is 3.6.

Edit:

- This error also occurs in others online python enviroments.
- I tried using python 3.7.4 in my docker container, like repl, but didn't work.

Comment: Are you using the current version of pytz?

Comment: That was the problem ! I've been using a 2017 version. It works perfectly after upgrading pytz via pip. Thanks you so much !

Comment: you should answer yourself with this information and mark question as answered :)